# Iphone sdk : Tab Character inside a textview

Tags: iphone, uitextview

How can I display a Tab (`\t`) on a `UITextView`?

I have a small piece of code (Example Below) which is well formatted with tabs and newlines, but when I view this code on a text view it does not show the tabs, though it does show the newlines.

```
@interface Animal : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *imageURL;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

UITextView remove Tab characters from text, but you can replace it with blank space.

```
description = [description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\t" withString: @"    "];
```

Comment: Tabs are not 4 spaces, if they follow text. It's more like "jump to next modulo 4 position in the line"

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the `UITextView` class simply does not show tab characters, which is entirely possible, due to the fact that the user cannot enter a tab with the built-in keyboard.  If this is the case, there is always the option of simply doing a replace on tabs to four spaces.  If you need to later find those tabs, you could replace it with a tab followed by four spaces, since it seems that the tab is not displayed, it would not make a visual difference.

The other possibility is that the width of the `UITextView` does not permit showing the tabs and so they are ignored.